# Modify Shopify Checkout page css

Tags: shopify

Based on answers to this question, I've added BOTH checkout.scss.liquid (for responsive checkout, which is what I am using) and checkout.css.liquid (when scss one failed to do anything) to Assets. According to the answers I found, Shopify will search for these filenames and include them on the checkout pages. This doesn't work for me.

One of these answers also included a screenshot of the Checkout settings page (Settings > Checkout > Customize checkout). The screenshot shows a lot more options than what I see. All I see are:

1) "Use a logo" drop down

2) Tagline

3) Order Summary and Text Entry Fields - Background

4) Colors - Accent

For example, the screenshot shows 3 options under Colors - Accent, Buttons, Call to Action. (would be nice to be able to change the button color without trying to get the css file to work)

Comment: Where are the original answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use custom CSS for the checkout unless you're in the Shopify Plus plan. More details at: https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/checkout-scss-liquid

[image]

In all other plans you just able to use the options you see in your theme customizer (like you already named).